# Is there any government that managed to help local (national) content creators by regulating the big streaming giants?

Tags: canada, freedom-of-speech, technology

I have recently heard about the Canadian Bill C-10 and read [more about it](https://www.ctvnews.ca/politics/is-the-government-trying-to-regulate-the-videos-you-post-what-you-need-to-know-about-bill-c-10-1.5414080). There seems to be a lot of criticism about it and few arguments in favor of it:

#### Pros

- "<<The bill is not about what Canadians do online. It is about what the web giants do not do, which is to support Canadian stories and music,>> he said in the House of Commons on May 4.We have and will continue to improve the bill so that it can serve Canadian creators."

#### Cons

- "sustained criticism from internet and free speech experts"
- "Michael Geist, a University of Ottawa law professor and the Canada Research Chair in internet and e-commerce law, has called it a “dangerous” attack on free speech."
- "<<When we are in a place in Canadian history where we are using social media platforms as the public square, it is important to protect the voices of Canadians and how they express those voices in those spaces… When the government goes so far as that are regulating what people are saying or posting, it has gone too far,>> said Conservative MP and digital government critic Rachael Harder at a committee hearing on May 3."

I am wondering if any other government managed to regulate (at least partially) what users are posting online, so that local content creators have an advantage.

Comment: Does China count? Not sarcasm, I'm asking because China is a rather special case.

Comment: @Peter. Yes, China counts.